# matlab equation system solver

Tags: matlab, variables, system, intervals, equation

i can solve the system of equations for an exact value of "q":

```
[A,B,C,Y]= solve('825*cos(A)+792*cos(B)-446.687*cos(C)=187.069','825*sin(A)+792*sin(B)-446.687*sin(C)=694.126','446.687*cos(C)-280.446*cos(2.778+B)=550','446.687*sin(C)-280.446*sin(2.778+B)=Y')
```

but i need solutions according to variable q=121:10:501:

```
[A,B,C,Y]= solve('(q+704)*cos(A)+792*cos(B)-446.687*cos(C)=187.069','(q+704)*sin(A)+792*sin(B)-446.687*sin(C)=694.126','446.687*cos(C)-280.446*cos(2.778+B)=550','446.687*sin(C)-280.446*sin(2.778+B)=Y')
```

Comment: he just wants to solve the equation for different values of the parameter q... see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1;
for q = 121:10:501
    [A(i),B(i),C(i),Y(i)] = solve(['(',num2str(q),'+704)*cos(A)+792*cos(B)-446.687*cos(C)=187.069'],['(',num2str(q),'+704)*sin(A)+792*sin(B)-446.687*sin(C)=694.126'],'446.687*cos(C)-280.446*cos(2.778+B)=550','446.687*sin(C)-280.446*sin(2.778+B)=Y')
i = i+1;
end
```

Comment: sory but it does not work Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
> In solve at 160 
 
A =
 
[ empty sym ]
 
 
B =
 
[ empty sym ]
 
 
C =
 
[ empty sym ]
 
 
Y =
 
[ empty sym ]
 
Warning: Explicit solution could not be found. 
> In solve at 160 
Error using mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

Error in sym/subsasgn (line 1464)
            C = mupadmex('symobj::subsasgn',A.s,B.s,inds{:});

Comment: Then try ... catch disp(sprintf('no solution for q=%d',q))